# API testing using protractor+jasmine

Tags: node.js, protractor, frisby.js

Does anybody using protractor with jasmine to do API testing. While searching for this I get to know that using frisby.js we can do API testing. But, my doubt is that whether protractor or jasmine directly supports/provides functions for API testing. Did anybody tried this?  If so, what is the approach that I need to follow ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor is meant for e2e testing and e2e tests are supposed to test the flow of an application from user standpoint, in spite of that you should test your API calls not directly but rather through testing user actions and if actions perform as intended it means the API that they rely on work.

If you want to do tests for API to catch errors early without having to run full e2e test suite you should use frisby.js as you've mentioned to confirm all APIs are A-OK  and you can follow then with e2e tests when you are sure that all should be working.

IMO it's better to use the tools for what they were designed.